# How to parse the ENUM value

Tags: apex, data-types

How could we pass an get a value from an enum inside a method.

According to the below code snippet, how could I pass the value of the parameter to severity__c  in Note__c instance??

```
enum severity {LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH, CRITICAL}
public static Note__c create(String head, String body, severity sev) {
    return new Note__c(
        Head__c = ntype,
        Body__c = body,
        severity__c = severity.valueOf(sev) ??
  ); 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're after the [`name()` method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_enum.htm).

> **name**
>
> Returns the name of the Enum item as a String.

eg.

```
enum severity {LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH, CRITICAL}
public static Note__c create(String head, String body, severity sev) {
    return new Note__c(
        Head__c = ntype,
        Body__c = body,
        severity__c = sev.name()
  ); 
}
```